# Issue with Spring-boot API bidirectional creating/updating

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So I built the API with a crud on spring boot, the issue arises due to the bidirectional nature of the entities.

I can create it fine manually through the application (non-api) and it appears with children and all.

However, once the API is up, I try to post it (to create) a JSON such as this:

```
{
    "idReserva": 1,
    "comentarios": "",
    "fechaIngreso": "0019-07-15",
    "fechaSalida": "0019-10-30",
    "cantidadDePersonas": 3,
    "usuario": {
        "idUsuario": 1,
        "nombres": "test",
        "apellidos": "test",
        "contrasena": "1234",
        "codUsuario": "USU01",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "foto": ""
    },
    "pagos": [
        {
            "idPago": 1,
            "tipo": "Efectivo",
            "total": 1500
        }
    ],
    "habitaciones": [
        {
            "idHabitacion": 1,
            "descripcion": "Habitación Ejecutiva",
            "tipo": 3,
            "numero": "5",
            "codHabitacion": "HAB01",
            "precio": "1500 dolares"
        }
    ]
}
```

The issue comes that in my "create" method inside the repository, I can't receive the nested entities, it does create the "reserve" entry in the database, but it doesn't give it its children

```
    List<Pago> listPagos = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Pago pago : reserva.getPagos()){
        log.info(pago.getIdPago()+"");
        pagoService.create(pago);
        listPagos.add(pago);
    }
    reserva.setPagos(listPagos);
```

I tried something such as that above to obtain each "pago"(payment) entity from the json and then create it/add it to reserve, since I need it to have the fields of its children payments in the database, but when I log the entities I receive "null" as if it's not receiving anything, is there any specific way I need to obtain the nested entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so after a few hours of working around it, I found the issue. the API itself was missing something crucial, when you want to save inside the resource (api) layer, before you actually .save() using the service layer, you want to create an instance of the child entity, using a For: loop pass each entity inside the Json to an instance of that child, and JPA automatically will create them, and add them to the parent entity as well.

Example:

```
for (Habitacion habitacion : reserva.getHabitaciones()){
            habitacion.setReserva(reserva);
        }
        for (Pago pago : reserva.getPagos()){
            pago.setReserva(reserva);
        }
        Usuario usuario = reserva.getUsuario();
        usuario.setReserva(reserva);
```

(this is inside the createReserva method from the resource layer)